# Feasible approximations for programs with bilinear constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have an optimisation problem of the form
\begin{array}{cccll}
  \min &f(x) \\
  \text{s.t.}& g_{1}(x) \leq s \\
  & g_{2}(x) \leq t \\
  & st \leq C \\
\end{array}

where my variables are $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$, and the functions $f, g_{1}, g_{2}$ are convex in $x$, and $C$ is a constant such that the program is feasible. Is there a general approach for solving such problems? **I would like to find a feasible point which is a good approximation in the sense that the value of the objective at the feasible point is close to the optimal value.** I am aware of [McCormick relaxation](https://optimization.mccormick.northwestern.edu/index.php/McCormick_envelopes) as a general technique for dealing with bilinear forms but this approach doesn't seem to return a feasible point. If it helps, it may be assumed that both $s, t$  are positive and may be bounded above by some constants $C_{s}$ and $C_{t}$.